# ZK-STARK vs ring-ct size and verification

Tags: ringct, transaction-size

How does the transaction size of ZK-STARK transactions compare with ring-CT? Also I understand it requires a lot of ram and computing power to create a ZK-STARK, does it take the same amount of ram and computing power to verify the transaction if you're only receiving it?

Comment: zkSTARK constructions uses an algorithm called the Fast Reed-Solomon Interactive Oracle Proof of Proximity. It is considered faster than the mainstream zkSNARKS. It uses ZKP friendly cryptographic hash functions such as Pedersen and Poseidon Hash Functions instead of the elliptic curve constructions used in zkSNARKs. The main issue with zkSTARKs currently is their size.